# Matlab Algorithm and Output File

Tags: matlab, function

I am working on a homework problem for a Matlab course. This is the problem :

Construct an m-file function mom that follows the flow diagram for the algorithm shown on slide 5. Notice that the output is given not to the screen but into a file called output.txt and also has a given structure (see slide 6).

In your script call this function with the following inputs (place these inputs into your script file as shown and then call the mom function  as mom(x,r,name,filename);)

```
x = [1 3 2 5 3 3 7 4 3 4 5 8 2];
r = 4; 
name = ‘Your name here’; 
filename = ‘output.txt’; 
mom(x,r,name,filename);
```

**I am also attaching the algorithm flowchart and the output file structure.**

My main script code looks like this:

```
x=[1 3 2 5 3 3 7 4 3 4 5 8 2 ];
r=4;
name= 'Matthew Haskell';
filename='output.txt';
[xbar,sn]=mom_Haskell(x,r,name,filename);
out= fopen('Output.txt','w');
fprintf(out,'\t\t\tCalculation by: %s\n\n',name);
fprintf(out,'The average is %.4f while the %.2f th moment is %.2f', xbar,r,sn);
```

My function file code looks like this:

```
function[xbar,sn] = mom_Haskell( x,r,name,filename )

n=length(x);
xbar=mean(x);

num=0;
den=0;

for k:1:1:n
     num=num+(x(k)-xbar)^r;
     den=den+(x(k)-xbar)^2;
end

sn=(num/n) / (den/n)^(r/2);

end
```

So far, I have encountered a problem with the function file and being able to output it from the main file. I believe there is a problem with the variable sn, I am not sure how to fix this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You inserted the same image twice

Comment: Thanks for that Daniel, I fixed it!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "for k:1:1:n" is that correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the syntax with the for-loop:

```
k=1:1:n
```

instead of

```
k:1:1:n
```

For the sake of completeness, it is worth knowing that if the step is 1, you can easily omit such step. So the instruction

```
k=1:1:n
```

is the same as

```
k=1:n
```

Also, according to the given specifications (second slide) the second `fprintf()` should be corrected as well. Such specifications says that:

- `xbar` must have 4 decimal places, and `%.4f` is correct
- `r` must be an integer, so `%.4f` is not correct. You need `%d` for integers
- `sn` should be floating point with 6 decimal places, but `%.2f` will show a floating point with just 2 decimal place. Use `%.6f` instead.